# Docker file The current working > directory does not contain a project or solution file

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core

On issuing command: `docker build -t honda-api:build .`

> Step 7/10 : RUN dotnet restore  ---> Running in beedd0465f48 MSBUILD :
> error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working
> directory does not contain a project or solution file.

Folder structure look like this

```
        Domain/
            Honda.Domain/
                Honda.Domain.csproj
        API/
            Honda.API/
                Honda.API.csproj
        Dockerfile
```

Docker file content

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 
    WORKDIR /home/app 
    COPY . . 
    COPY ./Domain/Honda.Domain/Honda.Domain.csproj Domain/
    COPY ./API/Honda.API/Honda.API.csproj API/
    
    RUN dotnet restore 
    RUN dotnet publish ./Honda.API.csproj -o /publish/ 
    WORKDIR /publish ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5001;http://+:5000 
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Honda.API.dll"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't copy a `.sln` file at root level that groups all your projects, you need to run `dotnet restore` over each one of the project directories or `.csproj` files, i.e.:

```
RUN dotnet restore ./API
RUN dotnet restore ./API/Honda.API.csproj
```

---

However, I wouldn't follow your approach of copying everything following the same project structure and then the `.csproj` files with a custom one, better keep everything as it is ad follow [this approach](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/).

Something like this (also, probably using the runtime image for running the app, instead of the sdk one, and using `Release` configuration):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /app 

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY ./Domain/Honda.Domain/*.csproj ./Domain/Honda.Domain/
COPY ./API/Honda.API/*.csproj ./API/Honda.API/
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY . ./
WORKDIR /app/API/Honda.API
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o publish 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/API/Honda.API/publish  ./
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5001;http://+:5000 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Honda.API.dll"]
```

I have not tested that, but hopefully you can tweak it and fix any minor issues it has.

Comment: This def. puts me on the right track. I'm making progress and I reached to step 17 of 19. Now I'm having error invalid from flag value build: pull access denied for build, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: hmm try with `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1` image instead